# How does firebird db handles user authentication?

Tags: mysql, database, authentication, firebird

I have an fdb file from which I'd like to recover data. Maybe something is wrong or I do not understand how it works but I was under the impression that the user authentication was handled by the server. I loaded the fdb file in my machine and I can see the table structure but it throws me an "invalid password" message when I try to browse the tables.

Ultimately I would like to export the data to another mysql server. So if there is a shortcut I could take to get there it would be great.

I'm way more fluent in Mysql and Sqlite so maybe there's a basic firebird concept I do not get.

Firebird server version: 2.5.2 on windows
I used FlameRobin 0.9.2 to browse the db

I keep getting `Your user name and password are not defined`.

Comment: What tool do you use to "see the table structure"? What version of Firebird?

Comment: What is the exact error (include GDS code and SQL code)?

Comment: the default username/password on windows is sysdba/masterkey. If you didn't change it it should work.

Comment: Well, next question then is are you connecting to the DB with username and password or did you left those blank in the DB description? If you left them blank and do not connect to the DB via `"Connect as..."` option then trusted authentication is used and if you don't have in your Firebird server user with the same name as your current OS username, then you get the `"Your user name and password are not defined"` error. Use the `connect as` option (right click on the DB in the Flamerobin) and connect as the `sysdba` user then you have all the rights on the DB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use the default password `masterkey` and user `SYSDBA` 
With the firebird, the password is on the server and not in the database